# Complex nested trait struct

Tags: struct, rust, traits

I am trying to decode APER messages and have issue creating nested structs with traits. I am using the [asn1](https://github.com/melvinw/rust-asn1) library, but I have provided an example to illustrate the issue.

I need a model that can take a value that can be any struct (more or less).

Using boxes does not work since the `serial` trait is `Sized`. I cannot seem to get generics to work either since the `decode` function does not return the type.

How can I get past this?

```
use std::fmt::Error;

pub trait serial: Sized {
    fn decode(&self) -> Result<Self, Error>;
}

pub struct Middle {
    pub bottomCode: i32,
    pub value: Box<dyn Bottom>,
}

impl serial for Middle {
    fn decode(&self) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let code = 1;
        if code == 1 {
            Ok(Middle {
                bottomCode: code,
                value: Box::new(BottomA { a: 1 }),
            })
        } else {
            Ok(Middle {
                bottomCode: code,
                value: Box::new(BottomB { b: 1 }),
            })
        }
    }
}
pub trait Bottom: serial {}
pub struct BottomA {
    pub a: i32,
}
impl Bottom for BottomA {}

pub struct BottomB {
    pub b: i32,
}
impl Bottom for BottomB {}
```

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Bottom` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/lib.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     pub value: Box<dyn Bottom>,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Bottom` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `BottomA: serial` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:32:6
   |
32 | impl Bottom for BottomA {}
   |      ^^^^^^ the trait `serial` is not implemented for `BottomA`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `BottomB: serial` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:37:6
   |
37 | impl Bottom for BottomB {}
   |      ^^^^^^ the trait `serial` is not implemented for `BottomB`
```

The `serial` trait represents the `APerElement` trait I'm trying to use from the ASN1 library, thus the return type and signature.

I want to be able to call `Middle.decode()` which will result in all children being decoded alongside it, and any children of those etc.  For that reason, it made sense to implement `serial` for it as well.

How would someone achieve such behavior? Is it possible?

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. The compiler has provided a warning about this.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What does a trait requiring Sized have to do with being unable to have trait objects of that trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53987976/155423); [The trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45116984/155423); [Unable to create a polymorphic type because the trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39412626/155423); .  If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: [trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57668019/155423)

Comment: Your question would be improved if you explained why you need to have the code structure that you are attempting. Why would you implement `decode` taking a reference to `Self` and then return a `Result<Self, _>`? Why does `Bottom` require that all implementors also implement `serial`?

Comment: See also [How to implement `serde::Serialize` for a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50026869/155423); [How can deserialization of polymorphic trait objects be added in Rust if at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44231020/155423)

Comment: Wow, you sure work fast Shepmaster. Thanks for your reply, I hope my edit has made my question more understandable :)
The serde example looks interesting, perhaps I am looking for serialization